# how to convert "\327\220\327\250\327\225\327\236" to hebrew?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, memory, unicode

I'm debugging my C code

and I want to know the value of a chars array.

the problem is that it is seen like this:

`0x63d7c4c8 "\327\220\327\250\327\225\327\236"`

how can I convert to Hebrew chars, via eclipse debug window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441474/chinese-characters-in-variable-values-while-debugging
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882378/java-console-not-reading-in-chinese-characters-correctly

Comment: @JoshLee, but these links look like Chinese to me! (sorry, couldn't resist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bash ~ $ printf "\327\220\327\250\327\225\327\236\n"
ארומ
bash ~ $
```

Not sure you can change it in the debug window, but take a look [here](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/).